# Sorting does not work on Language change , until the page is reloaded manually

Tags: angular, sorting, translate

The application supports 2 languages. I have a dropdown, which has a list of items. I want to sort the items alphabetically in both the languages. 
The sorting works fine, but when the user switches to a different language, the items are translated but are not sorted until the page is reloaded

sort function

```
private sort(value: any) {
return value.sort((a, b) => {
  return this.translate
    .instant(a.label)
    .localeCompare(this.translate.instant(b.label))

})

}
```

one of the sample function using this sort function

```
private inititem() {
this.dataService
  .getitems(this.Id)
  .pipe(
    switchMap((itemlist: ItemDto[]) => {
      return of(this.sort(itemlist))
    })
   )
  .subscribe(

  ****
)
}
```

Comment: So trigger the code to resort. So break logic up into a method where you can rerun that portion.

Comment: this.translate.onLangChange.subscribe(this.sort(this)) like this?

Comment: try re-initializing the array which stores the languages with sorted data. This should happen when the language changes event is fired.